# I have a 230 V, 3-phase connection. Where do I get 230 V from?

Tags: power, high-voltage, three-phase

I’m in bit of a puzzle here. I have a 10 HP/230 V/3-phase air compressor that I am trying to hook up to power. I currently have 3-phase 480 V and a 75 kVA delta-wye transformer.

I originally thought the air compressor would be hooked up on the 208 side of the transformer but I was wrong.

What approach should I take?  Where should I get the 230 V, 3-phase connection from?

Comment: Did you read the manual of the air compressor? Manufacturer and model number of the compressor?

Comment: I think you may need a transformer like these https://temcoindustrial.com/product-guides/transformers/three-phase-control-transformer-selection-guide/480volt-three-phase-control-transformer#400Y A 480Y/277 Primary - 400Y/231 Secondary. You should check for 50 or 60 Hz and the kVA needed.

Comment: But the air compressor comes with a VOLTAGE CONVERSION KIT SIMPLEX - 5HP FROM 230V/3 PHASE TO 460V/3 PHASE , wouldn’t that take care of the issue as far as getting the right voltage ?

Comment: I might not take getting a *CONVERSION KIT - 5HP* coming with a *10 HP/230 V/3-phase air compressor* in good humour.

Answer (score 2):

You would require a three phase auto-transformer rated as follows:

Capacity: 15 kVA

Input voltage: 3 x 480 V

Frequency: 60 Hz (3 x 480V utility supply is generally 60 Hz - to be confirmed)

Output voltage: 3 x 230 V

[image]

Comment: The OP has a 3 x 480 V incoming supply (line-to-line voltage 480V). The motor is rated 3 x 230 V (requires line-to-line voltage 230 V).

Comment: Yes, 3 phase voltage is specified line-to-line. For transformers and for motors. You need a different transformer to get 230 VAC. Or, if you aren't using the compressor at full capacity, it might work at 208 VAC, read your user's manual carefully.

Comment: But the air compressor comes with a VOLTAGE CONVERSION KIT SIMPLEX - 5HP FROM 230V/3 PHASE TO 460V/3 PHASE , wouldn’t that take care of the issue as far as getting the right voltage ?

Comment: Hi Ronaldo, Even I came across 'CHAMPION VOLTAGE CONVERSION KIT SIMPLEX - 10HP FROM 230V/3 PHASE TO 460V/3 PHASE'. However, there's absolutely no information on what is supplied.  460V - 3 Phase and 480V - 3 Phase are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

It's not delta wye.  Delta and wye are two very different configurations.  The 230 volt specification on the name plate signifies operation on 208 volt or 240 volt between phases.  Delta/Wye on a transformer is a typical indication from a manufacturer that the particular transformer can be used on both configurations.

Comment: "*Delta/Wye on a transformer is a typical indication from a manufacturer that the particular transformer can be used on both configurations.*" No, delta-wye in transformers means that one side is wired in delta and the other in wye (or "star"). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-wye_transformer. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).